# Calculate running count on grouped df by more than one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I want to calculate running count on the basis of the customer_id, date and status so -

```
Sample df- 

| id | order_id | customer_id | status | date |
| -------- | -------------- |-------|------|-------|
| 1  | 101 | 123 | X | 24-07-2021|
| 2  | 101| 223 | X | 24-07-2021|
| 3  | 101 | 223 | X | 24-07-2021|
| 4 | 101 | 123 | Y | 24-07-2021|
| 5  | 101| 123 | X | 24-07-2021|
| 6  | 102 | 123 | X | 25-07-2021|
| 7  | 101| 123 | Y | 24-07-2021|

Expected result - 

 | customer_id | status | date | cumulative_count |
 | ----------|-----|----------|------------|
 | 123 | X | 24-07-2021|1|
 | 223 | X | 24-07-2021|1|
 | 223 | X | 24-07-2021|(1+1)|
 | 123 | Y | 24-07-2021|1|
 | 123 | X | 24-07-2021|(1+1)|
 | 123 | X | 25-07-2021|(1+1+1)|
 | 123 | Y | 24-07-2021|(1+1)|
```

Due to some reason, I am unable to format the table, apologies for the same.

Comment: Do you want the output to look like that string? If you want numerics, try `df.groupby(['customer_id', 'status']).cumcount() + 1`

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan no I dont want the output to look like that it was just to explain the calculation. Also how i can add the column to expected result df?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)-

```
df['cumulative_count'] = df.groupby(['customer_id', 'status']).cumcount() + 1
```

**Output**

```
id order_id customer_id status         date  cumulative_count
1   1       101         123      X    24-07-2021                 1
2   2        101        223      X    24-07-2021                 1
3   3       101         223      X    24-07-2021                 2
4    4      101         123      Y    24-07-2021                 1
5   5        101        123      X    24-07-2021                 2
6   6       102         123      X    25-07-2021                 3
7   7        101        123      Y    24-07-2021                 2
```